# Pythonw.exe version=36+ always failed and report appcrash report with ucrtbase.dll

Tags: python-3.x, conda, windows-7-x64, pythonw

ENV=win7x64

20GB free disk space on each disks.

Used to work with python3.5.2.
Python3.5 from official release, Python 3.5.2 from Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.
Both of them work well.

MSVC 2005-2022 runtime x86 x64 installed.

Try to upgrade python3.8(3.6+) all failed.

1. Install python3.6+ from official release. `Python.exe` worked, but `pythonw.exe` and idle failed without any error report.
2. Install python3.6-3.8 from Anaconda3-2018-2021. Conda(python3.6-3.7)will fail with `APPCRASH REPORT pythonw.exe ucrtbase.DLL` below.

**pythonw.exe 3.6.5150.1013 5abd3212 ucrtbase.DLL 10.0.16299.15 70f70cc4 40000015 000000000006b71f 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1 2052 7c91 7c91ffc054a06a19bae511ac86fd4989 1e3a 1e3a1cfe3de7d661be48e9d60cfb8b11**

Conda(python 3.7-3.8) will not show any report, but find entry_point ERROR below.

```
Extract: anaconda-2021.05-py38_0.tar.bz2
  0%|          | 0/339 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 674, in map
  File "concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 600, in map
  File "concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 600, in <listcomp>
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 645, in submit
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 584, in _start_queue_management_thread
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 608, in _adjust_process_count
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
  File "multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 83, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 73, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 
[2964] Failed to execute script entry_point
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
```

Note that pythonw.exe(py35) icon is different from pythonw.exe(py36+) icon. I guess it might be caused by runtime? How to fix this problem?

Ok. Bad news. Still stucked here.

What I have tried:

1. Win7x64 `Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64` installed.
2. HKLC & HKCU `/SOFTWARE/PYTHON` deleted.
3. Anything related in SYS.Path and User.Path cleared.
   path=`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`
   No `PYTHONPATH`&`PYTHONHOME` . No user `PATH`.
4. JDK `JAVAHOME` deleted.
5. `anaconda clean --yes`.
6. MSVC runtime 2008-2022 all installed.
7. CLose all antivirus soft.
8. Restart Computer.

Problem is still there.

1. `Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe` installed, python ipython idle spyder jupyter work well.(py 3.5.2)
2. Clean Anaconda3, uninstall Anaconda3.

3.For `Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe` installation(reg anaconda3 as system python3.7 by default), during almost the end below.

```
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(324): Shortcut cmd is d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['d:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', 'd:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py', '"%USERPROFILE%/"']
```

I got a CRASHreport below.

```
APPCRASH
python.exe
3.7.3150.1013
5cc0c771
ucrtbase.DLL
10.0.17134.12
587decd7
40000015
000000000006e76f
6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
2052
99f9
99f9768885038458efd17b3ff3bc92c8
eff0
eff0e13a5c9d3da6d6b491ef4a5a8088
```

Close the crash report window then.

```
WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(46): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
```

Start up menu created, run python activate powershell got fatal error.

```
initfsencoding... no module named 'encoding'
```

4. For `Anaconda3-2021.05-Windows-x86_64.exe`, installation will return `file not found winerror` during entry_point.py like below.

```
Extract: anaconda-2021.05-py38_0.tar.bz2
  0%|          | 0/339 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 674, in map
  File "concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 600, in map
  File "concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 600, in <listcomp>
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 645, in submit
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 584, in _start_queue_management_thread
  File "concurrent\futures\process.py", line 608, in _adjust_process_count
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
  File "multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 83, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 73, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。
[4780] Failed to execute script entry_point
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

No start up menu created.

It seems that only Anaconda3-4.2.0(py3.5.2) can work on this computer.
If I try official release installation. All python3.5-3.8 can be installed, and All python(python.exe) in cmd can be running.
But only start menu`IDLE`(py35 pythonw.exe) will work.
Click any `IDLE`py36+(pythonw.exe) will not got any error message or new window.

Answer (score 0):

My final decision is to reinstall the win7 os. Yes it's done. No need to struggle to find solutions any more.